# Не рисуется текстура с большим разрешением

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

Я не могу вывести большое изображение в libGDX, в desktop проектк. У меня есть изображение с размером 9494x13082 пикселей и я вывожу его через `batch.draw (texture, 0, 0, width, height);`.А вместо текстуры libGDX нарисуйте черный квадрат. Если я сжимаю изображение до 60% и более, все работает нормально. Я попытался использовать TextureRegion, но это тоже не помогает. Скажите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема. Может, у меня недостаточно ОЗУ?

Я работаю в Linux, OpenGL ES 2.0, 2GB Ram, минимальная оперативная память для Java - 1 ГБ, максимум - 2 ГБ.

Comment: Не возникает ли каких-либо исключений? Что с потреблением памяти? Проверьте его через jconsole/jvisualvm. Проверьте максимальный размер текстуры для вашей системы.

Comment: Исключений нет( Максимальный размер пишет 8192, текстура, очевидно, больше. Возможно из-за этого и не рисует. Можете подсказать, как я могу обойти ограничение без сжатия? Например, нарезать текстуру кусочками и выводить

Comment: К сожалению, я не специалист по libGDX и не могу подсказать решения. Рекомендую задать новый вопрос. Судя по малому числу просмотров этого вопроса задавать новый стоит на основном, английском stackoverflow.

Comment: Спасибо) Я и там вопрос задал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, на многих старых устройствах максимальный размер текстуры 1024x1024.

А вообще, в [доках](https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/LibGDX-Textures#max-texture-size) сказано про это:

> Generally, most modern computers allow for at least 4096x4096
>   textures, but if you want to be really safe, you can limit yourself to
>   2048x2048. If you are targeting Android, iOS, WebGL, or another OpenGL
>   ES device, you might be safer sticking with 1024x1024 or less, unless
>   you are absolutely sure of your target audience.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Вручную поделил текстуру, сделал так, чтобы каждая часть была не больше 1024 на 1024. Всё отлично выводится, но FPS с 60 упал до 4. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём проблема.

Comment: @Ryder95 это уже лучше отдельным вопросом спросить.

Comment: Помогите, пожалуйста. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/741420/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%83-%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9