# Как вывести большую текстуру с максимальной оптимизацией

Tags: opengl, libgdx, текстура

Здравствуйте!

Пытаюсь писать приложение на `LibGDX`, который использует `OpenGL`.

Есть текстура примерно 9000 на 13000 пикселей.

Моя видеокарта позволяет выводит текстуры размером максимум 8192 на 8192, так что при выводе получается чёрное окно вместо текстуры.

Разбил своё изображение на 117 частей (так, чтобы каждая была не больше 1024 на 1024) и вывел их последовательно, как мозаику.

В итоге `FPS` с 60 просел до 4. Как мне вывести текстуру правильно без потери качества?

Comment: А как вы размещаете все эти пиксели на экране? Может можно что-то не выводить или заранее уменьшить текстуру?

Comment: А том то и суть, что текстура должна быть пиксель в пиксель оригиналом. Надо, чтобы при приближении всё было чётко видно. Но при отдалении, конечно же, всё начинает дико тормозить. Ну, то, что можно не выводить, я не вывожу. но в итоге, когда надо вывести всё, начинает тормозить дико